# PHP - Delete Item from Hash Table (array) using array_filter

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

In PHP, I know there is no official way to delete items once they have been put into an array. But there must be a "best-method" solution to my problem. I believe this may lie in the `array_filter` function.

Essentially, I have a shopping cart object that stores items in a hashtable. Imagine you can only ever buy one of any item at a time.

I do

```
add_item(1);
add_item(2);
remove_item(1);
```

`get_count()` still returns 2.

```
var $items;


function add_item($id) {
    $this->items[$id] = new myitem($id);
}

function remove_item($id) {
    if ($this->items[$id]) {
        $this->items[$id] = false;
        return true;
    } else {    
        return false;
    }
}


function get_count() {
    return count($this->items);
}
```

What do people think is the best method to use in get_count? I can't figure out the best way to use array_filter that simply doesn't return false values (without writing a seperate callback).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No official way?  Sure there is!  [Unset](https://www.php.net/unset)!

```
<?php

class foo
{
    var $items = array();


    function add_item($id) {
            $this->items[$id] = new myitem($id);
    }

    function remove_item($id)
    {
        unset( $this->items[$id] );

    }


    function get_count() {
            return count($this->items);
    }
}

class myitem
{
    function myitem( $id )
    {
        // nothing
    }
}

$f = new foo();

$f->add_item( 1 );
$f->add_item( 2 );

$f->remove_item( 1 );

echo $f->get_count();
```

Also, is this PHP4?  Because if not, you should look into some of the SPL stuff like [ArrayObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) or at least the the [Countable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) and [ArrayAccess](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interfaces.

### EDIT

Here's a version using the interfaces directly

```
<?php

class foo implements ArrayAccess, Countable
{
    protected $items = array();

    public function offsetExists( $offset )
    {
        return isset( $this->items );
    }

    public function offsetGet( $offset )
    {
        return $this->items[$offset];
    }

    public function offsetSet( $offset, $value )
    {
        $this->items[$offset] = $value;
    }

    public function offsetUnset( $offset )
    {
        unset( $this->items[$offset] );
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return count( $this->items );
    }

    public function addItem( $id )
    {
        $this[$id] = new myitem( $id );
    }
}

class myitem
{
    public function __construct( $id )
    {
        // nothing
    }
}

$f = new foo();

$f->addItem( 1 );
$f->addItem( 2 );
unset( $f[1] );

echo count( $f );
```

And here's a version as an implementation of ArrayObject

```
<?php

class foo extends ArrayObject
{
    public function addItem( $id )
    {
        $this[$id] = new myitem( $id );
    }
}

class myitem
{
    public function __construct( $id )
    {
        // nothing
    }
}

$f = new foo();

$f->addItem( 1 );
$f->addItem( 2 );
unset( $f[1] );

echo count( $f );
```

Comment: Get rid of the isset condition ;)

Comment: Oh, I guess it's not needed.  I didn't test the code, but I guess it doesn't throw a warning with unset() after all.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($this->items[$id]) {
```

May return a warning, should use array_key_exists or isset.

unset() seems cleaner than assigning false when removing an item (will also get rid of your count problem).

Answer (score 3):

+1 to both Peter's and Mario's answers: using `unset()` is the correct way to remove items from an array.

I just wanted to leave a note to explain why your method wasn't working. Using `count()` will count the number of values in an array. `false`, though you could imagine it as meaning "nothing", is still actually a value. Typically if you want to actually specify "no value" then use `null`.

You can also unset an array element by setting it to `null`, though look at the code below to see the difference.

```
$x = array("a", "b", "c");

var_dump(isset($x[0]));   // bool(true)
var_dump(isset($x[1]));   // bool(true)
var_dump(isset($x[2]));   // bool(true)
echo count($x);           // 3

$x[2] = null;
var_dump(isset($x[2]));   // bool(false) -- the value is not set any longer
echo count($x);           // 3  -- but it doesn't remove it from the array

unset($x[1]);
var_dump(isset($x[1]));   // bool(false)
echo count($x);           // 2
```